# Status of Data in Rollback of Large Transaction in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a data warehousing procedure that downloads and replaces dozens of tables from a linked server to a local database.  Every once in a while, the code will get stuck on one of the tables on the linked server because the table on the linked server is in a state of transition.  I am under the assumption that since the entire procedure is considered one transaction commit, when the procedure gets stuck, none of the changes made by the procudure so far would have committed.  But the opposite seems to be true, tables that were "downloaded" before the procedure got stuck would have been updated with today's versions on the local server.  Shouldn't SQL Server wait for the entire procedure to finish before the changes are durable?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MYIMPORT

AS

BEGIN


SET NOCOUNT ON

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION.SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TABLE1')
DROP TABLE TABLE1

SELECT COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3 
INTO TABLE1
FROM OPENQUERY(MYLINK, 'SELECT COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3 FROM TABLE1')

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION.SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TABLE2')
DROP TABLE TABLE2

SELECT COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3 
INTO TABLE2
FROM OPENQUERY(MYLINK, 'SELECT COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3 FROM TABLE2')
--IF THE PROCEDURE GETS STUCK HERE, THEN CHANGES TO TABLE1 WOULD HAVE BEEN MADE ON THE LOCAL SERVER WHILE NO CHANGES WOULD HAVE BEEN MADE TO TABLE3 ON THE LOCAL SERVER

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION.SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TABLE3')
DROP TABLE TABLE3

SELECT COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3 
INTO TABLE3
FROM OPENQUERY(MYLINK, 'SELECT COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3 FROM TABLE3')


END
```

Comment: I don't see any `BEGIN TRAN` in the stored procedure...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server treats each of the statements in the procedure as a separate transaction.  Need to add 'BEGIN TRANSACTION' and 'COMMIT TRANSACTION' to group the transactions as one.

Answer (score 0):

In short: stored procedure != transaction. SQL Server doesn't create separate transactions for stored procedures. You should manage transactions by yourself. Please see this link: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/06/02/sql-server-stored-procedure-and-transactions/